# how to provide injectables to service when Testing with NestJs Test.createTestingModule function?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I am trying to set up my test suite for a specific service which takes in a repository and two other services at the constructor parameter level injection using Nest's built-in Dependency Injection (DI).
The application is working fine no issue there. But when testing it returns:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AdjustmentService (?, RetailAdjustmentService, AdjustmentFileService). Please make sure that the argument AdjustmentRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

i know there must be something i am doing wrong but the docs were not of much help regarding that.

here is the constructor of that specific service i am testing :

```
export class AdjustmentService {
  constructor(
    private readonly adjustmentsRepository: AdjustmentRepository,
    private readonly _retailAdjustmentService: RetailAdjustmentService,
    private readonly adjustmentFilesService: AdjustmentFileService
  ) {}
//service functions here...
}
```

and here is my test

```
import { AdjustmentFileService } from "@/services/adjustmentFile.service";
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { AdjustmentService } from "./adjustment.service";
import { Repository } from "typeorm";
import { AdjustmentEntity } from "@/entities/adjustment.entity";
import { getRepositoryToken } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { RetailAdjustmentService } from "@/services/retail/retailAdjustment.service";

describe("Adjustment Service", () => {
  let adjustmentService: AdjustmentService;
  let adjustementRepository: Repository<AdjustmentEntity>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AdjustmentService,
        AdjustmentFileService,
        RetailAdjustmentService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(AdjustmentEntity),
          useValue: {
            save: jest.fn(),
            createQueryBuilder: jest.fn(),
            delete: jest.fn(),
            where: jest.fn(),
            execute: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    adjustmentService = module.get<AdjustmentService>(AdjustmentService);
    adjustementRepository = module.get<Repository<AdjustmentEntity>>(
      getRepositoryToken(AdjustmentEntity)
    );
  });

  describe("updateAdjustment", () => {
    it("should update the adjustment", async () => {
      const repoSpy = jest
        .spyOn(adjustementRepository, "save")
        .mockResolvedValue({ id: 1 } as AdjustmentEntity);

      const adjToUpdate = new AdjustmentEntity();
      adjToUpdate.id = 1;
      adjToUpdate.pilars = "RT";
      adjToUpdate.amount = 15000;

      expect(
        adjustmentService.updateAdjustment(1, adjToUpdate)
      ).resolves.toEqual({ id: 1 });

      expect(repoSpy).toBeCalledWith(adjToUpdate);
    });
  });

  it("should return a list of adjustments", async () => {});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to create mocks of these services, which you should in unit tests, then you should make [custom providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) that have a `provide` property of the class you want to mock and a `useValue` property of the mock to use. For example, `AdjustmentFileService`'s mock might look something like

```js
{
  provide: AdjustmentFileService,
  useValue: {
    upload: jest.fn()
  }
}
```

You're on the right track with the `getRepositoryToken` approach, but as your `AdjustmentRepository` is a class you directly inject, you need to use `AdjustmentRepository` as the `provide` value as well.

[This repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) has a lot of testing examples and might serve as a good reference.

Comment: Thanks @Jay McDoniel, much appreciated. Right Now, i am trying to find an efficient way to accomplish that since those services are quite big and mocking them one by one is quite troublesome. Any idea on how to combine useFactory for those providers or even if it's a good idea?

Comment: You can use a tool like `@golevelup/ts-jest` to automatically create mocks for the providers they are supposed to represent. The repository linked has a few examples with that as well